# Why this is a martingale

Tags: stochastic-processes

When I read the book "An introduction to Stochastic Differential Equations" by Evans, I am confused at Step 3 in the proof of existence Theorem of Ito diffusion.

> Let $ \mathbf{X}$ be a ito diffusion defined as
>   $$
> \left\{\begin{aligned} d \mathbf{X} &=\mathbf{b}(\mathbf{X}, t) d t+\mathbf{B}(\mathbf{X}, t) d \mathbf{W} &(0 \leq t \leq T) \\ \mathbf{X}(0) &=\mathbf{X}_{0} \end{aligned}\right. .
> $$
>
> To prove the existence of $ \mathbf{X}$, we use a sequence of $ \mathbf{X}^k$ which is defined as 
>   $$
> \left\{\begin{aligned} \mathbf{X}^{0}(t) & :=\mathbf{X}_{0} \\ \mathbf{X}^{k+1}(t) & :=\mathbf{X}_{0}+\int_{0}^{t} \mathbf{b}\left(\mathbf{X}^{k}(s), s\right) d s+\int_{0}^{t} \mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{X}^{k}(s), s\right) d \mathbf{W} \end{aligned}\right. .
> $$

In the proof, it make use of the fact that $$
\mathbf{X}^{k+1}(t)-\mathbf{X}^{k}(t)
$$ is martingale. However, I can not see it directly. I know that $$
\int_{0}^{t} \mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{X}^{k}(s), s\right) d \mathbf{W}
$$ is a martingale. But I cann not see that the part 
$$
\int_{0}^{t} \mathbf{b}\left(\mathbf{X}^{k}(s), s\right)-\mathbf{b}\left(\mathbf{X}^{k-1}(s), s\right) d s
$$
is also a martingale.

Comment: I look at the book, I can't see where he claims it is a martingale. Could you tell us where exactly it is said?

Comment: @Will  in proof of uniqueness an existence of SDE, step 3, it apply  the martingale inequality to it.

Comment: I see a martingale inequality applied to the martingale $(\int_{0}^{t} \mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{X}^{k}(s), s\right)-\mathbf{B}\left(\mathbf{X}^{k-1}(s), s\right) d \mathbf{W})_t$. You have an inequality which looks like $A\le B+C$ where $C$ is the maximum of the square of a martingale. Then he applies a martingale inequality to get something like $C\le C'$ and deduce that $A\le B+C'$.

Comment: @Will  Yes, I see that. I have a misunderstanding before. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misunderstood. Evans is never claiming that $X^{k+1} - X^{k}$ is a martingale since he never applies the martingale inequality to this quantity. Rather, he splits $X^{k+1} - X^{k}$ into two terms; one of which is a martingale and the other of which can be bounded by the fact that $b$ is Lipschitz.

Writing out all the details very explicitly, we have
$$X^{k+1} - X^{k} = \int_0^t b(X^{k}(s),s) - b(X^{k-1}(s),s) ds + \int_0^t B(X^{k}(s),s) - B(X^{k-1}(s),s) dW(s)$$
Hence, Evans is able to bound
\begin{align}
\max_{0 \leq t \leq T} |X^{k+1}(t) - X^{k}(t)|^2 \leq& \max_{0 \leq t \leq T} \bigg|2\bigg (\int_0^t b(X^{k}(s),s) - b(X^{k-1}(s),s) ds \bigg)^2 \\ & + 2\bigg( \int_0^t B(X^{k}(s),s) - B(X^{k-1}(s),s) dW(s) \bigg)^2 \bigg|
\\ \leq & 2T \int_0^T |b(X^{k}(s),s) - b(X^{k-1}(s),s)|^2 ds \\ &+  2 \max_{0\leq t \leq T} \bigg( \int_0^t B(X^{k}(s),s) - B(X^{k-1}(s),s) dW(s) \bigg)^2
\\ \leq&
 2TL^2 \int_0^T |X^{k}(s) - X^{k-1}(s)|^2 ds \\ & + 2 \max_{0\leq t \leq T} \bigg( \int_0^t B(X^{k}(s),s) - B(X^{k-1}(s),s) dW(s) \bigg)^2
\end{align}
where the last inequality uses the fact that $b$ is Lipschitz. Taking expectations yields
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[\max_{0 \leq t \leq T} |X^{k+1}(t) - X^{k}(t)|^2] \leq& 2TL^2 \mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_0^T |X^{k}(s) - X^{k-1}(s)|^2 ds \bigg] \\ & + 2\mathbb{E}\bigg[\max_{0\leq t \leq T} \bigg( \int_0^t B(X^{k}(s),s) - B(X^{k-1}(s),s) dW(s) \bigg)^2\bigg]
\\  \leq& 
2TL^2 \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[|X^{k}(s) - X^{k-1}(s)|^2] ds \\ & + 8 \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[|B(X^{k}(s),s) - B(X^{k-1}(s),s)|^2] ds
\\ \leq& 2TL^2 \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[|X^{k}(s) - X^{k-1}(s)|^2] ds \\ &+ 8L^2 \int_0^T \mathbb{E}[|X^{k}(s) - X^{k-1}(s)|^2] ds
\end{align}
where the second inequality follows by applying Fubini's theorem to the first term and the martingale inequality **only to the second term**. The last line (which is the bound Evans needs) then follows since $B$ is Lipschitz also.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was just stuck at that.